# Api Gateway with Lambda proxy integration via serverless not decoding response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've set up an API Gateway integration with a a lambda proxy integration, done automatically with the serverless framework. I usually have no problem with JSON returns, but doing this with http4k and kotlin, all my responses come back still base64 encoded.

Here are my logs for a response (from a mock inventory server)

```
f874ff6f-291c-4f9e-b106-f5f4a26e25e5) Endpoint response body before transformations: 
{     "statusCode": 200,     "headers": {         "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"     },     "body": "W3siaXRlbSI6eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJjOTNjM2MxYy1iMWFjLTRiMTUtYjI1Yi1lMWVmNWY2ZDYxNzIiLCJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsInN0b2NrIjoxLCJzdGF0dXMiOiJBVkFJTEFCTEUifSwicHJpY2UiOnsiaXRlbUlkIjoiYzkzYzNjMWMtYjFhYy00YjE1LWIyNWItZTFlZjVmNmQ2MTcyIiwiYW1vdW50IjoxMDAwLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6ImpweSJ9fV0=",     "isBase64Encoded": true }
```

And then

```
(f874ff6f-291c-4f9e-b106-f5f4a26e25e5) Method response body after transformations: W3siaXRlbSI6eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJjOTNjM2MxYy1iMWFjLTRiMTUtYjI1Yi1lMWVmNWY2ZDYxNzIiLCJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsInN0b2NrIjoxLCJzdGF0dXMiOiJBVkFJTEFCTEUifSwicHJpY2UiOnsiaXRlbUlkIjoiYzkzYzNjMWMtYjFhYy00YjE1LWIyNWItZTFlZjVmNmQ2MTcyIiwiYW1vdW50IjoxMDAwLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6ImpweSJ9fV0=
```

I've try to set binary media types to */*, but still no luck.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?